# Java Program to read a html page and save its content use javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to extract html content use javascript  (extract comments of users from website.. save as "Inspect Element" in chrome ) ,

I try this :

[Java Program to read a html page and save its HTML code in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176405/java-program-to-read-a-html-page-and-save-its-html-code-in-a-text-file)

But it just save html tag and content, not include content use javascript ( I mean I want save html when javascript is done ) . Please help.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: +1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102150/reading-htmljavascript-using-java?rq=1

Comment: @AjayThakur : Ty for link , but I don't really understand , you can take the example(source code) ?